# Set Data Validation Display style in Apps Script

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to set the dropdown display style in apps script?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After checking the documentation it looks like the API only allows you to choose between "Arrow" and "Plain Text".

The Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder) explains how to create data validation rules with a `DataValidationBuilder`. Most of the methods just set different [`DataValidationCriteria`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-criteria). Among those, the methods [`requireValueInList()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInList(String,Boolean)) and [`requireValueInRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinrangerange,-showdropdown) are the only ones that have a `showDropdown` parameter to set a dropdown, and the parameter's values can only be `true` or `false`. The default is `true`, which is equivalent to "Arrow" and `false` is equivalent to "Plain Text". As a boolean there's no third option for "Chip". Example:

```
// Set the data validation for cell A1 to require "Yes" or "No", with a dropdown menu.
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Yes', 'No'], true).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Looking at the Sheets REST API, which Apps Script is built on, the [`DataValidationRule`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#DataValidationRule) works in a similar way, but this uses `showCustomUi` instead of `showDropDown`. Still, the limitation is the same to show only the basic arrow and plain text.

It just seems like a feature that hasn't been implemented yet. Maybe the "Chip" was added a while after the basic dropdown. You can try to request it in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823917&pli=1).

Answer (score 3):

This feature does not exist as of today. I created an "issue [item](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/296461001)" in Google's issue tracker. Let's see if they implement it.

Comment: Please +1 with the button instead of commenting as such. Thanks!