# How can I get reducing number dropdowns based on what is left of a number in a separate cell

Tags: excel, validation, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am building a spreadsheet in google sheets that I hope will help me with capacity planning of my team and making sure I select the right topics for the team to work on.

I have the capacity of the team per week (in the revised capacity cell B1), and I have 7 big topics that they can pull tickets from. We're doing this on JIRA, but I want to make sure the tickets they take don't go over the value i'm allowing for the big rocks (over course of a few months)

[image: Current table (without validation)]

What I want is for the dropdowns to allow 1-14 as options in all of them if nothing is selected, then deduct whatever value is being selected from 14 so I can't choose more than 14 in one column.

If a sum of 14 gets selected here then the rest of the dropdowns will remain on Zero and you can't pick a number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can do that cleanly with just data validation rules. The problem is that the dropdown options for data validation don't allow you to set a range by formula. You can set individual values by formula or get the data from a range, so I was able to figure out a way by using a helper column. See the example:

[image]

[image]

The formula on the helper column starting on C3 is the following:

```
=IFERROR(SEQUENCE(B1+1-SUM(A3:A9), 1, 0), 0)
```

The issue with this is that when the capacity is reached and the only available value is 0, the other values that are already selected will be marked as invalid because the helper no longer contains them. Maybe if you could combine the A column with the sequence it could work but I didn't get that far.

If you're willing to use Apps Script you can use a script to do this instead (same sample data):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:A9") // define the range of your data validation column
  var capacity = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue() // define the cell with the capacity

  var erow = e.range.getRow()
  var ecol = e.range.getColumn()

  var vfirstrow = range.getRow()
  var vlastrow = range.getLastRow()
  var vcol = range.getColumn()

  if (ecol === vcol && erow >= vfirstrow && erow <= vlastrow) {

    var values = range.getValues().flat()
        
    var sum = values.reduce((tempsum, x) => tempsum + x, 0)

    var sequence = getSequence(0, capacity-sum < 0 ? 0 : capacity-sum )

    for (i = 1; i<=values.length ; i++){
      range.getCell(i,1).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(sequence.concat(range.getCell(i,1).getValue()), true))
    }
  }
}

function getSequence(start, end) {
  return Array(end + 1).fill().map((x, i) => i + start)
}
```

This uses `onEdit()` to edit the data validation rules for each row so they include the remaining available values along with the currently selected value so you won't get an error. Two issues with this are that it takes a second or two to update all cells, and the dropdown style revers to "Arrow" instead of "Chip", because [you cannot select Chip with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75397247/set-data-validation-display-style-in-apps-script/75402300#75402300).